# ASP.net - The status code returned from the server was: 500

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

First off, I am new to ASP.net, so this is new territory for me.

I am using Telerik controls on a VB.net project.  I get the following error as a javascript error for every action on the form. Changing any value, whether its a telerik slider, a radio button, asp:button, submit button, telerik rating.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while 
processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
```

I understand that the 500 error is an error thrown when the server doesn't have any more details, however I was hoping someone might have had a similar situation and can point me the right direction as I have a good feeling it has something to do with the Telerik controls.

I was able to submit the form using javascript however then I get the following error, and I don't know if they are related or not.

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or
cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and 
validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

Comment: I'm new to ASP.net, what am I looking for?  I did add the folowing after searching for a while but it didn't do anything:  <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" />

Comment: Disable "friendly error messages": http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-a-500-internal-server-error-for-all-asp-errors.html

Comment: Can you post your web.config and page code? You can also check this page: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/general-discussions/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed.aspx and do a search: http://www.google.com/search?q=Validation+of+viewstate+MAC+failed.+machinekey+telerik

Comment: Hey the script manager has an AsyncPostbackError event handler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerror.aspx) attach to it and check out what the error being reported is... this might give you more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exception a few times with telerik controls.  Try using an application like Fiddler

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

When your application gets to the point of the exception, it will give you more details.